# Reuse pseudocode tab when decompiling in IDA

Tags: ida, hexrays

When I press F5 in IDA to decompile, it always opens a new pseudocode tab, so over time many tabs open and I have to remember to close them. Can I make it so that F5 reuses an already open tab instead of opening a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> instead of <kbd>F5</kbd> to re-use the previous pseudocode tab rather than opening a new one.